# designing a dynamic html form for 64 fields

Tags: html

I have to design a form which takes inputs and inserts the values into a table which contains around 64 fields. The problem is that the inputs (64 entries) for the table should be retrieved from the user through the form only. I can't figure out how to design the form for this.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all 64 fields is a huge amount to enter try to reduce it if possible.

Normally user like to enter around 10 fields per page so you can build a **Setup Wizard** like form. First ask user to enter some fields lets say 10 then make button to go to next step and in next step again ask user to enter next 10 fields and on....